# Stripping headers response - Python

Tags: python, html, http, parsing

A typical `HTTP 1.0` header looks like this:

```
Server: nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 07:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 13471
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Dec 2015 02:42:32 GMT
Connection: close
ETag: "5674c418-349f"
Cache-Control: no-store
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!doctype html> // or <!DOCTYPE html>
# remaining of the page content here.
```

What's the easiest way for me to separate the beginning of the page (marked by `<!doctype html>` or `<!DOCTYPE html>` from the header of the `HTTP` request? For example

```
response = get_response() # get response is a string containing the page.
tokens = response.split("<!doctype html>") # won't work well.
return ''.join(tokens)
```

won't work well. I was looking into a way to split between the first half (header response) and the second half (the body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `find()` with a lowercase version of the response as follows:

```
response = """
Server: nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 07:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 13471
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Dec 2015 02:42:32 GMT
Connection: close
ETag: "5674c418-349f"
Cache-Control: no-store
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!doctype html> // or <!DOCTYPE html>
# remaining of the page content here.
"""

print response[response.lower().find('<!doctype html>'):]
```

This would print:

```
<!doctype html> // or <!DOCTYPE html>
# remaining of the page content here.
```

Or perhaps just search for `<!doctype`